# Web Api 2 Odata and versioning

Tags: odata, asp.net-web-api2

We are trying to implement an OData feed using Web Api 2 that will be consumed by various clients. When we try with Power Query for Excel we are seeing strange behavior which seems to relate to Power Query sets the following headers in the request:

MaxDataServiceVersion: 3.0

OData-MaxVersion: 4.0

- When using v3 version of the OData for Web Api we get a 404 response back (if same request are replayed in fiddler without OData-MaxVersion things work)
- When using latest v4 version for Web Api we get 403 response back (if same request are replayed in fiddler without MaxDataServiceVersion things work)

Is this a config issue or a bug?

Comment: Seems like a bug of the latest Power Query.